# by doing that we managed to save a lot of money

Tags: prepositions

1. Tom suggested that we cook our own food. That was a good idea.
   **By doing** that, we managed to save a lot of money.

Is there any preposition that could replace 'by doing' in the above sentence?
'From', 'through', 'by',...

Many thanks

Comment: You don't need **by** at all. *Doing that, we saved ...* has the same meaning.

Comment: "That way, we managed to save a lot of money" is an idiomatic way to say this.

Answer (score 1):

> **By doing** that, we managed to save a lot of money.

Possible prepositions to replace 'by doing' are **with** and **through**:

> **With** that, we managed to save a lot of money.

> **Through** that, we managed to save a lot of money.  (**By means of** that, we ...)

[**With** takes sense16](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/with#google_vignette)

> 16. PREPOSITION

> You use **with** to **introduce a current situation** that is a factor **affecting another** situation.
> **With** the win, the U.S. reclaimed the cup for the first time since 1985.

[**Through** takes sense16](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/through)

> 16. PREPOSITION

> If something happens because of something else, you can say that it happens **through** it.
> Synonyms: because of, by way of, by means of, by virtue of